Geometry Nodes - Seamlessly Animate Instances
so currently i'm working on some LED render stocks for my office. I want to seamlessly loop the floor instances in every 5 second. did anyone know how to do it? i'm a bit lost here. this is my nodes setup.



What kind of animation are you trying to create? Would you mind uploading the file?

the animation is just a simple offset instances with a geometry proximity up and down in the middle of the text. i already solved the proximity to make loop. my problem was just the instances that doesn't loop correctly.
here's the file. i tried to use vector distance
I'm new to Stack Exchange, so i'm uploading the file through WT

Thanks, I'm currently working on it and making decent progress :)

It took me a moment to figure out how the node tree actually works :D
The problem was that the animation was based on a noise texture, which is really hard to loop, so I replaced it with animation based on a sine wave.
How to make a looping animation based on a sine wave?

Phase offset - this value controls at which point in the sine wave does your animation start.
Multiply by tau - the sine function repeats periodically over tau (2pi) units of input, in this case tau frames. To get rid of the irrationality of tau, you need to multiply by it, and this effectively shrinks the period of your sine wave to a single frame.
Divide by intended period - this extends the period of the sine wave from 1 frame to the intended 150 frames.
Changing the limits - by default the sine wave outputs values ranging from -1 to 1, use this to change it to values that you prefer. Just remember to set "from min" to -1 and "from max" to 1.


Randomizing per instance
To randomize the animation per each instance to look close to your original unlooped animation, I added random values to the phase offset. I also separated it per axis and gave the random value node a different seed value for each axis. To achieve even more randomness, you can also try changing the period for each axis, just keep in mind that for the animation to loop seamlessly, your period has to be a number that your total animation length is divisible by.
I did it in Blender 4.0, so I apologize if the messes up your settings.
Also, I can't figure out how to install blend exchange, so here's the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17DCf_ZHqaa7idhW-w4XCmL1V3pqKOqlQ/view?usp=sharing
